# Deploying Go App with Firestore in Google App engine

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

When I run my web app with `go run main.go` , everything including Firestore works fine, but when I try to deploy it using `gcloud app deploy` I get the following error message:

```
Step #0:"google.golang.org/api/transport/grpc".ConnPool does not implement "google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConnInterface (missing Invoke method)
Finished Step #0
ERROR
```

Any help would be apreciated..

I was unable to post entire code because of stackoverflows limit, but it returns no errors when compiled normally so it should be fine.

Code looks something like this:

```
func loadPage(substring string) (*Equation, error) {

    projectID := "deepxcode"
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    dsnap, err := client.Collection("equations").Doc(substring).Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, err
    }
    var equation Equation
    dsnap.DataTo(&equation)
    fmt.Printf("Document data: %#v\n", equation)

    return &equation, nil
}
```

**Edit:**

Run `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug`, I get:

```
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cloud build failed. Check logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/builds/a7f82257-891d-43f0-8694-834bac2b4560?project=529812836358 Failure status: UNKNOWN: Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 981, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 110, in Run
    default_strategy=flex_image_build_option_default))
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 643, in RunDeploy
    ignore_file=args.ignore_file)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 416, in Deploy
    image, code_bucket_ref, gcr_domain, flex_image_build_option)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 289, in _PossiblyBuildAndPush
    self.deploy_options.parallel_build)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 449, in BuildAndPushDockerImage
    return _SubmitBuild(build, image, project, parallel_build)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/deploy_command_util.py", line 482, in _SubmitBuild
    build, project=project)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/cloudbuild/build.py", line 150, in ExecuteCloudBuild
    self.WaitAndStreamLogs(build_op)
  File "/google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/cloudbuild/build.py", line 195, in WaitAndStreamLogs
    + message)
```

Comment: is your vendor folder up to date?

Comment: Can you run `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` so we can see in more details what is happening since the ERROR you provided does not say anything.

Comment: @Stefan Sure, I've added the output to the post.

Comment: Did you check the Cloud Build logs as stated on the error message? Do they provide further error messages of the input? Also would you mind sharing your app.yaml file by removing any possible sensitive information? Have you run the prerequisite commands as suggested on the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/quickstart#before-you-begin): the most relevant being `gcloud components update` and `gcloud components install app-engine-go`?